# process is undefined in React

Tags: reactjs

I am building a simple React app that generates a QR code from data. I am interested in inspecting the memory usage when the QR code is generated. I am using the built process.memoryUsage() function but the app throws and exception

```
Uncaught TypeError: process__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__.process is undefined
```

I have tested some different solution, i tried to rollback the react script version to "4.0.3"  i tried to download the npm polyfill webpack but there is no success.

I am currently using these imports

```
 import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
 import process from 'process';
 import './App.css';
 const QRCode = require('qrcode');
```

The function looks like this

```
let stringData = JSON.stringify(qrData);
console.log("Number of chars in data" + " " + stringData.length);

QRCode.toDataURL(stringData, function (err, url) {
if(err) return console.log("error occured")
//window.location.href = url;

})
const used = process.memoryUsage();
for (let key in used) {
console.log(`${key} ${Math.round(used[key] / 1024 / 1024 * 100) / 100} MB`);
 }
}
```

Comment: React runs in the browser.

Answer (score 0):

[`process`](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html) is a Node.js API and is not available in the browser where your React app is running, which is why you see that error. If there is an available global `process` object, it is being polyfilled by something in your build tools, and will not have the [`memoryUsage` method](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#processmemoryusage).

There is no equivalent API for the browser, but some related APIs do exist. Note that this is an evolving space and some are non-standard, so be sure to read both the spec and documentation before considering any usage:

- [Device Memory API (MDN)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Device_Memory_API)
- [`Performance.memory` (MDN)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Performance/memory)

Answer (score 0):

You are using a built in `nodejs` package in a `react` app. Node executes on the server and has access to system level resources. React runs in the browser and does not. See [this article](https://logrocket.com/for/react-performance-monitoring/) for some tips measuring performance in React.